# Inserting into 2 tables PHP with subquery, last insert id, and prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have problem with inserting data into 2 tables directly using subquery and last insert id.

i have following codes

```
if (isset($_POST['recipient']))
    $recipient  = sanitize($_POST['recipient']);
if (isset($_POST['message']))
    $message    = sanitize($_POST['message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO message (senderID, message)
        VALUES (?,?)";

        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $userID, $message);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $newID = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO message_recipient (messageID, recipientID)
                     SELECT ?, userID
                     from user
                     where username = $recipient";

            if ($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
                         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "ii", $newID, $recipient);
                         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
                         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
            }
        }
```

for the $stmt2 ,it works well in phpmyadmin, but without the prepared statement. The first query works well, it can add data, but can't the second. Also, i dont know why the first query will insert 2 data, with first data correct and second false.

Is the way i get last insert id wrong, or my second query is false?

Any help given really appreciated. thank you so much

Comment: In your 2nd query change `where username = $recipient` to `where username = ?` as you are currently binding 2 params, but you only had 1 placedholder in your query.

Comment: still not working sir.. and the first query will still insert 2 data directly

Comment: Another typo $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql) should be $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql2) or overwrite sql again and remove sql2.